# Why i am getting undefined?

Tags: javascript

Here is my code:

```
var person = {
    name: 'Greg',
    year: 20
};
Object.defineProperties(person, {
    gender :{
        value: 'male'
    },
    edition : {
        value : 12
    },
    edition : {
        set:function  (No) {
            if (No===13) {
                console.log('Yes')
            };
        }
    }

})
console.log(person.edition)
```

looks like i did all right, did not change descriptors
any ideas?
thanks

Answer (score 1):

When you write `person.edition`, you are calling the get method. Which is not defined. To call the set method you need to do `assignment`. Try this:

```js
var person = {
    name: 'Greg',
    year: 20
};
Object.defineProperties(person, {
    "gender" :{
        value: 'male'
    },
    "edition" : {
        value : 12
    },
    "edition" : {
        set:function  (No) {
            if (No===13) {
                console.log('Yes')
            };
        }
        , get:function  () {
            return "hi";
        }
    }

})
console.log(person.edition)
person.edition = 13;
```

Comment: Where did you see `get` method ?

Comment: @RayonDabre `get` is a [getter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get), not a method. It's called automatically when you access the `edition` property. Here is a [tutorial](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects#Defining_getters_and_setters) if you are not familiar with getters and setters.

Comment: Something new for me! Detailed explanation will help!

Comment: @RayonDabre [This demonstrates getters and setters.](https://jsfiddle.net/ttnbcxy3/) (Code from the MDN page I linked.)

Comment: Thanks..Isn't same as `b:function() {
    return this.a + 1;
  }` Any specific difference ?